# How can I derive typeclass instances from constraint families that are in scope?

Tags: haskell, constraints, gadt, existential-type, quantified-constraints

**edit:** I have followed up with a more [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088443/how-can-i-use-a-constraint-family-thats-in-scope-to-prove-instances-within-the). Thank you answerers here, and I think the followup question does a better job of explaining some confusion I introduced here.

---

**TL;DR** I'm struggling to get proofs of constraints into expressions, while using GADTs with existential constraints on the constructors. (that's a serious mouthful, sorry!)

---

I've distilled a problem down to the following. I have a simple GADT that represents points called `X` and function applications called `F`. The points `X` are constrained to be `Objects`.

```
data GADT ix a where
  X :: Object ix a => a -> GADT ix a
  F :: (a -> b) -> GADT ix a -> GADT ix b
```

`Constrained` refers to containers whose objects are constrained by *something* and `Object` is that *something*. (*edit:* my real problem involves `Category` and `Cartesian` classes from [constrained-categories](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0))

```
-- | I can constrain the values within containers of kind `* -> *`
class Constrained (ix :: * -> *) where
  type Object ix a :: Constraint

-- | Here's a trivial constraint. A more interesting one might include `Typeable a`, for ex
instance Constrained (GADT ix) where
  type Object (GADT ix) a = (Constrained ix, Object ix a)
```

I would like to write an expression:

```
-- error: Could not deduce: Object ix Int arising from a use of ‘X’
ex0 :: GADT ix String
ex0 = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

And while the obvious solution works, it quickly becomes verbose when building larger expressions:

```
-- Typechecks, but eventually verbose
ex1 :: Object ix Int => GADT ix String
ex1 = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

I think the correct solution should look something like this:

```
-- error: Could not deduce: Object ix Int arising from a use of ‘X’
ex2 :: Constrained ix => GADT ix String
ex2 = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

But I still can't get that proof of `Object ix Int`.

I'm sure it's simpler than I'm thinking. I have tried adding constraints to the `Object` constraint family in the `GADT` class instance. I have tried offering constraints in the expression's signature. I have tried `QuantifiedConstraints`, although, I'm not sure I fully grasp it yet. Please help me wise ones!

---

**Runnable:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

module Test where

import Data.Kind
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Functor.Const

-- | I can constrain the values within containers of kind `* -> *`
class Constrained (ix :: * -> *) where
  type Object ix a :: Constraint

-- | Here's a trivial constraint. A more interesting one might include `Typeable a`, for instance
instance Constrained (GADT ix) where
  type Object (GADT ix) a = (Constrained ix, Object ix a)

-- | A demo GADT that has function application ('F'), and points ('X'). The
-- points are constrained.
data GADT ix a where
  X :: Object ix a => a -> GADT ix a
  F :: (a -> b) -> GADT ix a -> GADT ix b

-- -- Broken
-- -- error: Could not deduce: Object ix Int arising from a use of ‘X’
-- ex0 :: GADT ix String
-- ex0 = F show (X (3 :: Int))

-- Typechecks
-- but for larger programs becomes verbose, requiring many explicit constraints
ex1 :: Object ix Int => GADT ix String
ex1 = F show (X (3 :: Int))

-- -- What I want, but, it's broken
-- ex2 :: Constrained ix => GADT ix String
-- ex2 = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

Comment: Surely, `ex2` still needs to include at least the `Int` annotation? Or mayble you should use an example other than `show`, a function that's not polymorphic in its input.

Comment: Why don't you parameterise `GADT` on the constraints: `GADT :: (Type -> Constraint) -> (Type -> Type)`

Comment: @leftaroundabout agreed, the `Int` annotation would be needed in `ex2` to unify `Show a` with `Num a`

Comment: @Iceland_jack I've tried your approach but couldn't make it work either, though, it seems promising. I've asked a followup question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088443/how-can-i-use-a-constraint-family-thats-in-scope-to-prove-instances-within-the) where I hope to clarify why this problem exists in the first place for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context it's hard to say what's the best solution, but here are a couple of possibilities:

##### Avoid constraining at all

As it stands, your GADT doesn't seem to have much reason for restricting `X` to `Object`. Maybe this is just not needed?

```
data GADT ix a where
  X :: a -> GADT ix a
  F :: (a -> b) -> GADT ix a -> GADT ix b
```

Instead, the constraint could come from the *outside* when it's needed.

##### Bite the bullet of constraint lists, but make them nicer

If you have many different types in your expression that all need to fulfill the same constraint, you can use a helper like [`All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ixset-typed-0.5/docs/Data-IxSet-Typed.html#t:All)

```
ex2' :: All (Object ix) '[Int] => GADT ix String
ex2' = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

where there can be more types in the list in addition to `Int`; and/or you can make synonym constraints such as

```
type StdObjs ix = (Object ix Int, Object x Bool, ...)

ex2'' :: StdObjs ix => GADT ix String
ex2'' = F show (X (3 :: Int))
```

##### Propagate the constraints backwards through the data structure itself

If you do need the constraint on the `X` values, it may nevertheless be possible to express this in another way in the GADT. For example, if the function is *not* a general function but something that is already constrained to only accept `Object`s, you could have it like this:

```
data YourFunc ix a b where
  YourFunc :: Object ix a => (a->b) -> YourFunc ix a b

show' :: Object ix Int => YourFunc ix Int String
show' = YourFunc show
```

This doesn't directly help with the problem you were asking about, but maybe the function is shared or something. You could even have something like

```
class Object ix a => InferrenceChain ix a where
  type PreElem ix a :: Type
  propInferrence :: (InferrenceChain ix (PreElem a) => r) -> r
```

and then

```
data YourFunc ix a b where
  YourFunc :: InferrenceChain ix a
                 => (PreElem a -> a) -> YourFunc (PreElem a) a
```

Then in the end you could proof the `X` constraint from just putting in `Object ix String` on the outside and recursing over `propInferrence`. But this would probably get quite fiddly.

Comment: I've asked a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088443/how-can-i-use-a-constraint-family-thats-in-scope-to-prove-instances-within-the). Wrt eliding constraints, the follow up shows why I need them. Wrt a constraint list, I still think the boilerplate would become insufferably large. Wrt `YourFunc`, that'd introduce a ton of up front boiler plate (a new prelude), though, probably eliminate future boilerplate. Wrt `InferrenceChain`, I'm struggling to map it onto my problem, but maybe the followup helps explain better? Thank you btw!

Comment: woh, I just realized you're the author of the library I'm messing around with, `constrained-categories`, thanks for the library, it's amazing!

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear you find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

> I think the correct solution should look something like this:
>
> ```hs
> -- error: Could not deduce: Object ix Int >arising from a use of ‘X’
> ex2 :: Constrained ix => GADT ix String
> ex2 = F show (X 3)
> ```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't make any sense. The compiler is justified in pointing out that it doesn't know that `Object ix Int` is satisfied at this point, since all it knows is that `Constrained ix` may impose *some* constraint through `Object ix Int`.

#### A solution through quantification

So perhaps what you want is a constraint which says: "at this point, all `Object ix a` constraints I use are satisfied" - which we can try and do through quantification:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type Satisfied ix = forall a. Object ix a

ex2 :: Satisfied ix => GADT ix String
ex2 = F show (X 3)
```

Unfortunately, that gives us a GHC error:

```
• Quantified predicate must have a class or type variable head:
        forall a. Object ix a
• In the quantified constraint ‘forall a. Object ix a’
  In the type synonym declaration for ‘Satisfied’
```

Since `Object` is a type family and not a class or type variable.

##### Re-architecture

But... why is `Object` a type family? In fact, why does `Constrained` exist at all as a lawless class with no methods? If we want to exert constraints on combinations of containers and types, Haskell already gives us the means to do that - just use instance constraints!

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Object ix a

type Constrained ix = forall a. Object ix a
```

Because if we have

```hs
instance (...<some stuff>...) => Constrained Foo where
  type Object ix a = (...<some def>...)
```

we could translate that to

```hs
instance (...<some stuff>..., ...<some def>...) 
  => Object ix a
```

Which makes this example compile.

```hs
ex2 :: Constrained ix => GADT ix String
ex2 :: F show (X 3)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Unfortunately,  what I've simplified to `Constrained`, in my real problem, is actually `Category` and `Cartesian` from `cartesian-categories`, which are lawful with methods. I don't know a way, other than TypeFamilies (ie a constraint family, here) to express the idea of a class whose objects are arbitrarily constrained subtypes of Hask, so, I don't think the rearchitecture will work for this particular problem.

Comment: Do you mean the `categories` library? I think you need to provide a more motivating example as to why treating `Object` as a class doesn't work as an approach, because it's not obvious to me from looking at those classes.

Comment: shoot, so sorry, it's this one! https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0

Comment: actually, here's a direct link to the class: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Category

Comment: Your examples very much go down the same paths I walked. Wrt your idea to rearchitecture it, I've asked a [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088443/how-can-i-use-a-constraint-family-thats-in-scope-to-prove-instances-within-the) question that shows why I can't, namely, the `Object` is a typefamily that constrains the co/domain and is a requirement from another library.